# Actualizar tabla

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo una pagina dónde muestro la ficha de un empleado y los temas a los que pertenece.
Agrego y elimino los temas perfectamente pero me gustaría que se actualizase la tabla donde muestro esos temas automaticamente cuando agrego o elimino temas.

```
   $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/empleados-temas.ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:  form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (respuesta)            {
                                   
                                   toast.fire({
                                               icon:'success',
                                               title: 'Tema eliminado correctamente'
                                   }),
                                   ***AQUI ES DÓNDE HE PROBADO VARIAS OPCIONES** 
                                   //$('#tbl_temas').ajax.reload(null, false);
                                   //$('#tbl_temas').draw(true);
                                   
                                   }
});
```

Este es el código que recibe la respuesta de la consulta de agregar o eliminar, no muestro el código de la tabla dónde se muestran los temas pero indico que el id de esa tabla es: (tbl_temas)

Codigo html de la tabla

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table" id="tbl_temas" >
        <thead>
          <tr class="text-danger">
            <th>Temas Asociados</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Agrega el html donde tienes la tabla

Comment: ¿Qué hay en `respuesta`, pon un `console.log(respuesta);` y analiza. No veo que la uses para nada en tu código. No sabemos si la petición está trayendo algo, ni con qué estructura, todo dependerá de eso.

Comment: Por favor, añade la nfo que falta yendo a [edit] la pregunta. Abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de resppuesta. Incluso si te piden aclaraciones aquí en comentarios, procura responder extendiendo la pregunta.

Comment: En `respuesta` no deberías recibir solamente si la consulta ha sido `ok`, sino también los datos que te trae la consulta para poder usarlos.

Comment: Perdona pero no entiendo para que necesitas los datos de respuesta para poder refrescar la tabla donde se muestran los datos. Los datos están cargados correctamente en la tabla, si actualizo toda la página se ven, pero lo que quiero es evitar esto y sólo actualizar la tabla dónde se muestran los datos

Comment: Alguien sabe como poder actualizar solamente la tabla donde muestros los temas una vez agregado uno nuevo o eliminado uno de la tabla?